# how do i make this MYSQL query; regarding grouping of a row

Tags: php, mysql

wondering if someone has a clue on how to solve this:

I currently do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers
WHERE type!=''
```

it gives this outcome:

[image]

but what I need is to merge rows where companyemail is the same, while retaining the others who
dont have a companyemail:

[image]

I cant use GROUP BY/DISTINCT as it then omits the other unaffected rows, does anyone have an idea

Comment: Are those two fields mutually exclusive? If company email is set, then personal email must be empty, and vice versa? If so, you should be able to simply group by whichever of those two is actually set. (And if not - then you should provide a proper explanation of how a record with both of them set, should present in the result set in the first place.)

Answer (score 0):

Distinct without a group by should produce your required outcome.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3637a0d81e6ca4a8a220efc4132b0b0c